# Send array data using android spring framework

Tags: android, arrays, spring

I am using the Spring Rest framework for android in one of my projects. Its working fine while sending non array data but I am struck on how to send array data.

Following is the piece of code:

```
HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(UtilFunctions.getInstance().getUserName(getApplicationContext()),
            UtilFunctions.getInstance().getPassword(getApplicationContext()));

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);

    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

    formData.add("uid", UtilFunctions.getInstance().getUid(getApplicationContext()));
    formData.add("dataType", Constants.DATA_TYPE);
    formData.add("dataID", dealID);
    formData.add("sheetType", type);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(
            formData, requestHeaders);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);

    try {

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(AppConfigs.URL_FILE_UPLOAD , HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                String.class);

        String resp = response.getBody();

        Log.e("Response", resp);

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```